# Temporarily accessing gmail via http instead of https

Tags: gmail, https

I'm usually accessing gmail via https. Certain wifi providers (at airports for example) forbid https connections, but allow http. Is there a quick way to force gmail to use http? (http://gmail.com redirects to https://...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these WiFi providers forbid all https connections, then you are out of luck.  All gmail logins go over https, and there is no way to change that.  It's only once you're in the session that you have the option to use http instead of https.  Leaving your session unencrypted on public WiFi might not be the best idea either (see Facebook and Firesheep as an example).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done but you have to change a setting in your Account Settings beforehand.

[Taken from Google FAQ](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=74765)

> **Changing the HTTPS setting**
>
> We've recently made the 'Always use
>   https' setting the default behavior in
>   Gmail (the default used to be http).
>   Here's some background: If you sign in
>   to Gmail via a non-secure Internet
>   connection, like a public wireless or
>   non-encrypted network, your Google
>   account may be more vulnerable to
>   hijacking. Non-secure networks make it
>   easier for someone to impersonate you
>   and gain full access to your Google
>   account, including any sensitive data
>   it may contain like bank statements or
>   online log-in credentials.
>   Accordingly, we enable the 'Always use
>   https' option in Gmail by default.
>   HTTPS, or Hypertext Transfer Protocol
>   Secure, is a secure protocol that
>   provides authenticated and encrypted
>   communication.
>
> To disable or re-enable this feature
>   in Gmail:
>
> - Sign in to Gmail.
> - Click **Settings** at the top of any Gmail page.
> - Set 'Browser Connection' to 'Don't use https' or 'Always use https.'
> - Click **Save Changes**.
> - Manually change the URL to http://mail.google.com to start
>     accessing Gmail via http.
>
> Please note that selecting 'Always use
>   https' will prevent you from accessing
>   Gmail via HTTP (Hypertext Transfer
>   Protocol). If you trust the security
>   of your network, you can turn this
>   feature off at any time.
>
> If you use a public computer to check
>   your email, it's also important to end
>   each of your Gmail sessions by
>   clicking Sign out at the top of any
>   Gmail page and to close all Gmail
>   browser windows.